# Load balancing server affinity to specific destination

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I need organize load balancing for following application. I have instances of service A and service B running on one application server 1 and copy of these services running on app server 2. Services B interact with services A by HTTP. I want configure load-balancing such way that all requests from B to A will balancing on same node and will balance to another if component A not available. For example, request from B on AS1 will go to A on AS1 if A is OK and to AS2 if A on AS1 is failed.

I find `ip_hash` option of nginx, but it's not specify destination of request, it's only guarantee same destination for request from same IP. Are there any way to this?

Comment: May be you need `backup` parameter http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server

Comment: Ty, for my case with 2 servers it's work. But there is any solution for > 2 servers in group?

PS: @AlexeyTen, can you move your comment to answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: You could use external load balancer.